共有ドライブ上のスプレッドシートに作成した GAS がブロックされます
Google の共有ドライブ上に置いてあるスプレッドシートに作成した GAS を実行しようとすると「アカウントの選択」画面が表示されて、自分のアカウントを選択すると「このアプリはブロックされます」というメッセージが表示されて実行できず困っています。
実行できるようにする方法はないでしょうか？
自分のアカウントと共有ドライブは別ドメインですがスプレッドシートに対する編集権限があります。
以下のサイトも参照しましたが、問題は解決しませんでした。
Google Apps Script(GAS)初回実行で認証ブロックされる事象の原因
実行しようとしているスクリプトは以下の通りです。

function/1-0 情報取得

/**情報取得 */
function getInfo() {
  try{
    let data = form.getDataRange().getValues();//入力フォームのデータを取得
    // console.log(data)

    const PDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(data[3][6].split("/").slice(-1)[0])//PDF出力フォルダのIDを取得

    //受発注者情報
    let ClientAndVender = {
      "受注者情報": {
        "社名": data[3][1],
        "代表": data[4][1],
        "郵便番号": data[5][1],
        "住所": data[6][1],
        "建物": data[7][1],
        "電話番号": data[8][1],
        "Email": data[9][1],
      },
      "発注者情報": {
        "社名": data[3][3],
        "代表": data[4][3],
        "郵便番号": data[5][3],
        "住所": data[6][3],
        "建物": data[7][3],
        "電話番号": data[8][3],
      }
    }

    //取引情報
    let maxRow = form.getMaxRows()
    if(form.getRange(maxRow,1)!==""){form.insertRows(maxRow)}
    let TransactionLastRow = form.getRange(maxRow, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
    let TransactionInfo = {
      "件名": data[1][0],
      "注文内容": []
    }
    
    for (let i = 12; i < TransactionLastRow; i++) {
      TransactionInfo["注文内容"].push({
        "No": data[i][0],
        "摘要": data[i][1],
        "単価": data[i][2],
        "数量": data[i][3],
        "取引金額": data[i][4],
      })
    }

    //備考
    let Note = {
      "見積書": data[9][6],
      "注文書": data[15][6],
      "領収書": data[31][6]
    }

    //口座情報
    let PayInfo = {
      "銀行名": data[23][7],
      "支店名": data[24][7],
      "種別": data[25][7],
      "口座番号": data[26][7],
      "口座名義": data[27][7],
    }

    //締め切り日
    let ExpirationDate = {
      "見積書": data[7][6],
      "請求書": data[21][6]
    }
    console.log(ExpirationDate)

    /**------------------------入力不備の判定------------------------*/

    let client = ClientAndVender["発注者情報"]
    let vender = ClientAndVender["受注者情報"]
    let emptyClient = Object.keys(client).filter(key => !client[key]);
    let emptyVender = Object.keys(vender).filter(key => !vender[key]);
    let empty = emptyClient.concat(emptyVender)
    if(empty.length>0){
      Browser.msgBox("受注者情報、または発注者情報に不備があります。")
      return false;
    }

    if (TransactionLastRow === 12) {
      Browser.msgBox("摘要が入力されていません。")
      return false;
    }

    if(TransactionInfo["件名"] ===""){
      Browser.msgBox("件名が入力されていません")
      return false;
    }

    let emptyBank = Object.keys(PayInfo).filter(key => !PayInfo[key]);
    if(emptyBank.length>0){
      Browser.msgBox("口座情報の入力に不備があります。")
      return false;
    }

    return { PDFfolder, ClientAndVender, TransactionInfo, Note, PayInfo, ExpirationDate }
  }catch(e){
    if(!exit(e))return
  }
}


function/1-2 注文書

/**注文書作成 */
function CreateOrderForm() {
  try{
    //情報取得関数から返り値を受け取る
    if(!getInfo())return;
    const { PDFfolder, ClientAndVender, TransactionInfo, Note, PayInfo, ExpirationDate } = getInfo();

    //すでに出力用シートが存在する場合、削除する
    if (ss.getSheetByName(`[注文書]出力用`)) { ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheetByName(`[注文書]出力用`)) }

    let format = ss.getSheetByName("注文書");                //フォーマット取得
    let output = format.copyTo(ss).setName(`[注文書]出力用`)  //コピーを出力用とする

    /**------------------------入力情報の整形------------------------*/
    let uuid = Utilities.getUuid();                         //UUIDを生成
    let client = ClientAndVender["発注者情報"]              //発注者オブジェクト
    //フォーマットに入力しやすいよう配列として整形
    let clientInfo = [                                                             //クライアント会社名と住所
      [client["社名"] + "\n\n" + '〒' + client["郵便番号"] + '\n' + client["住所"] + '\n' + client["建物"]], 
      [client["電話番号"]],                                                         //電話番号
      [client["代表"]]                                                              //代表者名
    ]
    let vender = ClientAndVender["受注者情報"];//受注者オブジェクト
    let venderInfo = [
      [vender["社名"]],                                                             //受注側会社名
      ['〒' + vender["郵便番号"]],                                                   //住所
      [vender["住所"]],
      [vender["建物"]],
      [vender["電話番号"]],                                                         //電話番号
      ["代表取締役 " + vender["代表"]]                                              //代表者名
    ]
    let total = TransactionInfo["注文内容"].reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur["取引金額"], 0);//注文の合計金額を算出

    let date = new Date();//今日のDateオブジェクト
    let today = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd');//今日の日付にフォーマット
    

    let note = Note["注文書"].split("\n")//備考を改行区切りで配列に

    /**------------------------情報入力------------------------*/
    output.getRange('G3').setValue(uuid)                   //G3にUUID
    output.getRange('B4').setValue(vender["社名"])          //B4に受注側会社名
    output.getRange('C7').setValue(TransactionInfo["件名"]) //C7に件名
    output.getRange('G7:G9').setValues(clientInfo)         //G7からG9に発注側会社情報
    output.getRange('G13:G18').setValues(venderInfo)       //G13からG16に受注側会社情報
    output.getRange('C9').setValue(total)                  //C9に合計金額
    output.getRange('G4').setValue(today)                  //G4に発効日

    //備考が4行未満なら
    if (note.length < 4) {
      while (note.length !== 4) {note.push("")}//空白を加えて4行に揃える
    }
    //備考が4行より多ければ
    if (note.length > 4) {
      output.insertRowsAfter(14, note.length - 4)//差分の行数をシートに加える
    }

    let noteRow;//備考の行数を監視する
    //備考配列をループ
    for (let i = 0; i < note.length; i++) {
      noteRow = 14 + i                                 //備考を入力する行を算出
      output.getRange(noteRow, 2).setValue([note[i]]) //1行ずつ備考を入力
    }
    output.getRange(14, 2, note.length, 3).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false);//備考を入力した範囲を罫線で囲む
    noteRow += 5//注文内容を入力する行に影響しないように調整して渡す

    let orderRow;//注文内容の入力行の監視
    // 注文内容をループ
    TransactionInfo["注文内容"].forEach(function (order, index) {
      orderRow = noteRow + index;//注文内容の入力行を備考の行数と注文内容のインデックスから算出
      let orderArr = Object.values(order);//オブジェクトを配列に直す
      let orders = [orderArr.slice(0, 2).concat(["", ""]).concat(orderArr.slice(2, 5))]//間に空白を入れて微調整
      output.getRange(`C${orderRow}:E${orderRow}`).merge();//注文内容入力行のセルを一部結合
      output.getRange(orderRow, 2, 1, 7).setValues(orders).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);//注文内容を入力し、罫線で囲む
    })

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();//入力内容を反映
    PDFexport(output, PDFfolder, ClientAndVender["発注者情報"]["社名"], "注文書", orderRow)//PDF出力
  }catch(e){
    if(!exit(e))return
  }
}


スクリプトの動作でブロックされているのであれば、その中身が分からない事には第三者は判断のしようが無いと思います。質問はあとからでも編集できるので、必要に応じて内容を見直してください。 / 共有ドライブではなく、実行アカウントのドライブ上に直接保存して実行した場合はどうなるかも試してみてはどうでしょうか？

ご回答ありがとうございます。スプレッドシートをマイドライブにコピーして実行すると正常に動作します。
